# Hessian matrix equal to zero

Tags: multivariable-calculus

The function  $x\times y + e^{-x\times y}$  has the points that form $x$-axis and $y$-axis as critical points, how can I prove that they are points of minimum, the Hessian matrix in those points is equal to zero.

Comment: That function is the composition of $t\mapsto t+e^{-t}$ and $(x,y)\mapsto x\times y$. The first one has a global minimum at $t=0$, is decreasing for $t<0$ and increasing for $t>0$.

Answer (score 1):

The gradient is $(y - y e^{-xy}, x - x e^{-xy})$ and the Hessian is
$$\begin{bmatrix}y^2 e^{-xy} & 1 + xy e^{-2xy} \\ 1 + xy e^{-2xy} & x^2 e^{-xy}\end{bmatrix}.$$

If $x=0$ then the Hessian is
$$\begin{bmatrix} y^2 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}.$$
One can check that this matrix is positive semi-definite (e.g. by the version of [Sylvester's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_criterion) for positive semi-definite matrices).

Similarly if $y=0$, then the Hessian is
$$\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 1 & x^2\end{bmatrix}$$
which is also positive semi-definite.

Thus all critical points are local minima.